# Dispay flex row and uniformed sizes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like all my element to have the same height and the separator to cover all the height. How can I achieve that please ?

The separator is pink, you can see it here with a `height: 5em`

```css
.daddy {
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
}

.container {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.child1 {
  width: 3em;
  height: 10em;
  background-color: red;
}

.child2 {
  width: 3em;
  height: 15em;
  background-color: blue;
}

.separator {
  width: 10px;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="daddy">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the align items from container, all three columns will grow to fill the row

```css
.daddy {
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
}

.container {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  justify-content:center;
}

.child1 {
  width: 3em;
  background-color: red;
  height: 10em;         /* this is just to give it some height as no column currently has any height */
}

.child2 {
  width: 3em;
  background-color: blue;
}

.separator {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="daddy">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child1">
    </div>

    <div class="separator">
    </div>

    <div class="child2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```